# How to define initial DeliveryTag value for RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

When declaring a new Queue in RabbitMQ the `DeliveryTag` starts at one and increments serially for each published message.

Is it possible to define an initial value (other than "one") for the `DeliveryTag` when declaring the queue?

```
QueueDeclareOk QueueDeclare(string queue, bool durable, bool exclusive, bool autoDelete, IDictionary<string, object> arguments);
```

I tried without success searching for a custom argument for this purpose.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way. Delivery tag is not really meant to be set by the user, anyway.